# Correctly connecting Web App with MySiteHost in case of multiple mapping

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem

Current situation:

- there is a classic SP application (site collection created eg according to Team Site template) - default AAM is https: //intranet.xxx.local
- there is an application for MySite (created from MySiteHost template) - default AAM is https: //mysite.xxx.local
- there are 2 applications exactly like this, so when user goes to https: //intranet.xxx.local and clicks eg. to the SharePoint heading (top left corner), redirecting it to https: //mysite.xxx.local

Required functionality:

- it is necessary to extend the application, because it should also be accessible from the Internet
- the "normal" SP application will then be available for example. on url - https: //sp.xxx.sk
- if the user goes from intranet, then https: //intranet.xxx.local, the link to "mysite" should be https: //mysite.xxx.local
- if the user goes from internet, then https: //sp.xxx.sk , the link to "mysite" should be https: //my.xxx.sk

Questions:

- I understand correctly that it is enough to extend the wep app https: //intranet.xxx.local and https: //mysite.xxx.local and when I go from the Internet I will have correctly displayed URLs https: //sp.xxx.sk and https: //my.xxx.sk? Or is there anything else to be adjusted?
- Do I need additional Search Service settings when I use search?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have it down.  Extend the .local web app to the .sk address, and you should be good to go from the SharePoint side of things.  You will still need to make changes to your External DNS, firewall for routing traffic, etc.  No changes should be needed in search, just let it keep crawling the default zone, no need to add the extended URL to a content source or anything like that.